# PHP как закешировать curl_init()?

Tags: php, php-curl

Есть удаленный API с адресами у которого есть ограничения на подключения, допускается 60 новых подключений в минуту

С моей стороны логика такая: пользователь в поле пишет адрес и при каждом нажатие запускается аякс который запускает скрипт затем через Curl идет обращение к API

Как я понял при каждом запуске скрипт заново инициализуеться соединение curl_init() и вскором времени API перестает отвечать так как превышается лимит соединений

Пожалуйста подскажите как я могу закешировать curl_init()? или тут надо действовать по другому?

Comment: Зачем кешировать `curl_init` если он фактически не соединяется с АПИ? Кешировать надо ответ от АПИ, чтобы при тех же запросах лишний раз к АПИ не стучаться. Или связаться с АПИ и заплатить сумму денег за увеличение лимита запросов.

Comment: Как я понял curl_init запускает инициализацию подключения. Если её сохранить в переменную то можно использоваться много кратно и не нужно запускать каждый раз curl_init. Но проблема в том что скрипт запускается всегда заново когда аякс к нему обращается и получается так что каждый раз устанавливается новое соединение с API

Comment: Ресурс, возвращаемый `curl_init`, понятия не имеет куда подключаться, до тех пор пока ему не передадут опцию `CURLOPT_URL` . Потому кешировать его бессмысленно.

Comment: Как же мне поддерживать одно постоянное соединение с API?

Comment: Очевидно, что никак.

Comment: Неужели не кто на знает как тут быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, проблему решил следующим способом:

1. Нужно написать PHP-демона который сделает одно подключение, а потом, в цикле будет выполнять запросы по одному и тому же подключению
2. Чтобы отправлять и получать данные из этого запущенного PHP-демона нужно использовать вебсокеты

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть какой-то УРЛ и набор параметров, которые вы передаёте. Из них вам нужно построить уникальную строку (например, хэш sha). Эта строка будет ключом кэша.

При необходимости запроса, в проверяете в хранилище кэша этот ключ. Если ключ имеется, берёте данные из кэша и работаете с ними. Если ключа в кэше нет, выполняете запрос к апи, кладёте в кэш данные с этим ключом и обрабатываете данные.

Comment: К сожалению это не решает проблемы с количеством подключений